# POST route not redirecting after login

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport-local

I am creating app with login system (Passport JS). I have a little problem with logging locally. I have provided all necessary code, but the problem is, when I try to login (passport-local) the app redirecting me to the wrong route. There isn't similar problem with signing in with Google OAuth. What I mean:

Session config and passport initialization in `app.js`:

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'session',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: MongoStore.create({
        mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URI,
        // ttl: 10 * 120 // save session for
    }),
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
    }
  })
)
require('./config/passport')(passport);
require('./config/passport_log')(passport);
// is it even legal to have 2 or more passport configs?
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Passport local config in `passport_log.js`:

```
function(passport) {
    const verifyCallback = (username, password, done) => {
            LogUser.findOne({username: username}, 'username salt hash')
                .then((user) => {
                console.log(user)
                    if (!user) {console.log('invalid'); return done(null, false)}
                    const isValid = validPassword(password, user.hash, user.salt);
                    if (isValid) {
                        console.log('valid')
                        return done(null, user);
                    } else {
                        return done(null, false);
                    };
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    done(err);
                });
        };
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(verifyCallback));
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        console.log(user)
        done(null, user.id);
    });
    passport.deserializeUser((userId, done) => {
        LogUser.findById(userId)
            .then((user) => {
                console.log('deser')
                done(null, user);
            })
            .catch(err => done(err))
    });
}
```

It returns 'valid' after the code is executed.

`/login` POST and GET routes and `/private` GET route in `index.js`:

```
router.post('/login', 
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        successRedirect: '/private'
    })
);
router.get('/login', isNotLogin, (req, res) => {
    res.render('view/login');
});
router.get('/private', isLogin, (req, res) => {
    res.render('view/private');
});
```

And auth config from `auth.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    isLogin: function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            console.log('ok')
            return next();
        } else {
            console.log('not')
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
    },
    isNotLogin: function (req, res, next) {
        if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
            console.log('isnotok')
            return next (); 
        } else {
            console.log('isnotnot')
            res.redirect('/private');
        }
    }
};
```

And it returns `not` and `isnotok` in the console.

After trying to login, the console returns:

```
valid
POST /login 302 156.267 ms - 60
not
GET /private 302 83.408 ms - 56
isnotok
GET /login 200 87.810 ms - 3394
```

So it's redirecting me to `/private`, but then back to `/login`.

And honestly I have no clue where the error may be.

All of the code: https://github.com/kbilak/ToDoApp

Comment: The thing should be with the session. You should post how you initialize passport and the strategy. Also it's easy to debug what headers/cookies are being sent back and forth, as well as `req.user` on all endpoints above. That would show you where things break. Currently it's hard to tel...

Comment: Thank You for Your comment! I've posted the initialization of passport as well as the local strategy, and link to git repo with rest of the code. I've been trying to solve the problem for many days, but still, with no result. I'm assuming that the answer to this is going to be probably very easy, but I can't think of thing that could solve it.